# A square implies AA^{T} SPD

Tags: linear-algebra

If A is square and real valued, does is follow then that $AA^{T}$ is symmetric positive definite?
I really don't see how to work out. Does someone have a hint?

Comment: SPD is semi-positive definite?

Comment: Symmetric positive definite :)

Comment: Ahh.  So the answer is "almost", because if $A$ is not invertible, you will have zero eigenvalues (so it is positive semi-definite).  But as a first step, do you know why it is symmetric?

Answer (score 2):

1) $AA^T$ is symmetric:
$$(AA^T)^T=(A^T)^TA^T=AA^T$$
2) $AA^T$ is positive **semi**definite:
$$\langle AA^Tx,x\rangle=\langle Ax,Ax \rangle = \|Ax\|^2\geq 0$$

Answer (score 1):

There is never any shame in experimenting with "random" matrices. Try to find a nice matrix $A$ which is obviously singular. What can you say about the singularity of $AA^T$?

Comment: This is a nice comment, but I wouldn't consider it a proper answer to the question

Comment: I would like to understand your position better. Would you elaborate on this point? The OP asked *not* for the solution, but for a hint. I am quite new to this forum, but *not* to teaching. My hint would allow the OP to do the "hard" part himself, and discover that $AA^T$ can be indefinite.

Comment: I misread the question originally; your answer is fine. I thought he wanted to prove the matrix was psd.

Comment: Thanks. All is well. These things happen :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $\langle x,y \rangle = x^T y$ be the standard inner product on $\mathbb R^n$.  Now, let $x$ be an eigenvector of $AA^T$, and compute $\langle AA^Tx,x \rangle$ two different ways.